# How it happened that evolution of "mater" and "pater" is different despite their similar origin?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, vocabulary, proto-indo-european

With an addition of PIE relatives suffix **-ter-*, Eurasiatic **ama*, **apa* became Old PIE **mā-ter-s*, **pa-ter-s* (the final -s was later lost in late PIE)

But there is a difference: in Old PIE **māters* the "a" is a long vowel while in **paters* it is short (and Laryngalists even reconstruct **ph<sub>2</sub>ters*). So the question is how the two similar roots gave different vowels in PIE and how the Laryngealists are able to explain the conversion of a Eurasiatic vowel into a laryngeal?

Comment: The existence of Eurasiatic as a linguistic grouping higher than Indo-european is not widely accepted. Laryngeal theory, conversely, is widely accepted.  In particular, the difficulty with _*ph₂tēr_ is one of the problems that the Eurasiaticists would need to explain. Or to put it more plainly -- the problem you describe is actually evidence against those supposed Eurasiatic roots, in my opinion.

Comment: Laryngeal hypothesis is not accepted by the majority of Moscow school (Starostin's school) http://popgen.well.ox.ac.uk/eurasia/htdocs/nostratic.html

Answer (score 6):

Linguists who subscribe to the Laryngeal Theory (now it's the majority of researchers) don't have that problem because they don't reconstruct at the "Eurasiastic" level.

A laryngeal is reconstructed when Vedic i corresponds to Greek alpha, epsilon, or omicron:

*ph2ter - Vedic pita, Greek pater

With the word "mother", it's a bit different:

*meh2ter -Latin mater

Also, notice that in *ph2ter the last syllable is stressed, whereas in *meh2ter it's the first syllable.

Now we are waiting for your "Eurasiastic" explanation.